# Is it possible to have Visual Studio 2022 Project and repo in different locations?

Tags: git, visual-studio

For our work projects we have separate locations for C++ projects and the git repo that we cmake them from. Is there anyway for Visual Studio to set the repo location separate from the solution location?

Nothing I try seems to work.